# Use Isolate to sort list

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I have a non-primitive list which I would like to sort.

When I sort it, the UI thread is blocked and the app freezes for a few seconds.

I tried to avoid this by using dart's Isloate [compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) function but since the parameter sent to the compute function must be a primitive or a list/map of primitives ([send method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html)) it didn't work.

To conclude, is there any way to perform a list sort(non-primitive) without blocking the UI thread?

Edit: Clarification - I was trying to call a function through compute and I was passing a list of objects (which I got from a third party plugin) as an argument, those objects had a property of type Iterable and that caused everything to fail - make sure all the types are primitive or List/Map of primitives. With the answers I received and changing the type from Iterable to List it worked.

Comment: Use async and await.

Comment: Can you post uour sorting code.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu dart is asynchronous single threaded, all async and awaits are ran on the same thread + there isn't a any async sort method.

Comment: block UI for a few seconds while sorting list? you are storyteller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but you can sort a list of non primitive elements like this:

```
final List<Element> elements = [
  Element(id: 1),
  Element(id: 7),
  Element(id: 2),
  Element(id: 0)
];

elements.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
// or
elements.sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);
```

This would be a `print(elements);` output:

```
I/flutter ( 7351): [id: 0, id: 1, id: 2, id: 7]
```

And this would be the class `Element`

```
class Element {
  final int id;

  Element({this.id});

  @override
  String toString() => "id: $id";

  int compareTo(Element other) => this.id > other.id ? 1 : -1;
}
```

---

**Edit:** To make this asynchronously, you could do this:

```
Future<List<Element>> asyncSort() async {
  print("before sort: $elements");
  elements = await compute(_sort, elements);
  print("after sort: $elements");
  return elements;
}

static List<Element> _sort(List<Element> list) {
  list.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  return list;
}

print("before calling asyncSort(): $elements");
asyncSort();
print("after calling asyncSort(): $elements");
```

And this would be the output:

```
I/flutter ( 7351): before calling asyncSort(): [id: 1, id: 7, id: 2, id: 0]
I/flutter ( 7351): before sort: [id: 1, id: 7, id: 2, id: 0]
I/flutter ( 7351): after calling asyncSort(): [id: 1, id: 7, id: 2, id: 0]
I/flutter ( 7351): after sort: [id: 0, id: 1, id: 2, id: 7]
```

---

**Edit2:** If you want to send a compare function to `compute`, you could use a `Map` or a `List` of arguments with the list and the compare function and pass that instead of the list, because `compute` just takes one argument. Here is an example:

```
Future<List<Element>> asyncSort() async {
  print("before sort: $elements");
  Map args = {"list": elements, "compare": compare};
  elements = await compute(_sortWith, args);
  print("after sort: $elements");
  return elements;
}

static List<Element> _sortWith(Map args) {
  List<Element> list = args["list"];
  Function(Element a, Element b) compare = args["compare"];

  list.sort((a, b) => compare(a, b));
  return list;
}

static int compare(Element a, Element b) {
  return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: this is not async, I was talking about sorting a list without blocking the UI thread. If the list you were sorting was bigger that you would notice that the app freezes until it is done sorting.

Comment: This works but it's not perfect for my case, I have a list of objects that have multiple properties to sort by (example: List<Student> can be sorted by name, age, average grade etc). I tried extending your solution by sending a compare function but couldn't get it to work. is there any way to pass a compare function to the _sort function which is called by compute?

Comment: Thanks! I tried to pass a compare function which was not static, a bit of a bummer that you have to define a static function for every compare but it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i use compute, just put all parameters to a list, then call it in a List of dynamic object:

```
image = await compute(getCropImage, [copyFaces, streamImg]);

imglib.Image getCropImage(List<dynamic> values) {
    var face = values[0]; // copyFaces
    var image = values[1]; // streamImg
}
```